# Enable and Disable Text Box Using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, disabled-input

Here I try to Enable and Disable my text-box using Java Script.But my code is working fine in case of disable but not able to regain the enable state.I added my snippet below.Here I have used the following `JS` query  for the purposes.

> getElement(elm).setAttribute("disabled", true);
>
> getElement(elm).setAttribute("disabled", false);

**JS ATTEMPT**

```js
/*----------FUNCTION TO GET AN ELEMENT BY ID-------------------*/
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}
//==============================================================//
/*-------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE A TEXT BOX-------------------*/
function disable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).setAttribute("disabled", true);
}
//==============================================================//
/*--------------FUNCTION TO ENABLE A TEXT BOX------------------*/
function enable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).setAttribute("disabled", false);
}

getElement("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
disable("text-box2");
});
getElement("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
enable("text-box2");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box1"/>
<input type="text"  id="text-box2"/>
<button id="button">disable</button>
<button id="button2">enable</button>
```

**CSS SOLUTION**

Here I have a solution using `css` and it's working fine.In this method we faking the pointer by using the `css` property `pointer-events: none` .

```js
/*----------FUNCTION TO GET AN ELEMENT BY ID--------------------*/
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}
//==============================================================//
/*-------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE A TEXT BOX-------------------*/
function disable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).classList.add("disable");
}
//==============================================================//
/*--------------FUNCTION TO ENABLE A TEXT BOX-------------------*/
function enable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).classList.remove("disable");
}

getElement("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
disable("text-box2");
});
getElement("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
enable("text-box2");
});
```

```css
.disable{
    pointer-events: none ! important;
    opacity: 0.4 ! important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box1"/>
<input type="text"  id="text-box2"/>
<button id="button">disable</button>
<button id="button2">enable</button>
```

But I would like to have a solution without `css`. Is there a possible solution without `css`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove Attribute instead of setting it (disable) to false.

```js
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}
//==============================================================//
/*-------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE AN TEXT BOX-----------------*/
function disable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).setAttribute("disabled", true);
}
//==============================================================//
/*--------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE AN TEXT BOX----------------*/
function enable(elm){
    return getElement(elm).removeAttribute("disabled");
}

getElement("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
disable("text-box2");
});
getElement("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
enable("text-box2");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box1"/>
<input type="text"  id="text-box2"/>
<button id="button">disable</button>
<button id="button2">enable</button>
```

Comment: great answer bro ..:)

Comment: according to stackoverflow  it's takes about  5 mins to accept an answer after posting a question

Answer (score 1):

A different approach can be based on [input disabled attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> This Boolean attribute prevents the user from interacting with the input. In particular, the click event is not dispatched on disabled controls, and disabled controls aren't submitted with their form.

```js
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}
//==============================================================//
/*-------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE AN TEXT BOX-----------------*/
function disable(elm){
    getElement(elm).disabled = true;
}
//==============================================================//
/*--------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE AN TEXT BOX----------------*/
function enable(elm){
    getElement(elm).disabled = false;
}

getElement("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    disable("text-box2");
});
getElement("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
    enable("text-box2");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box1"/>
<input type="text"  id="text-box2"/>
<button id="button">disable</button>
<button id="button2">enable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}
//==============================================================//
/*-------------FUNCTION TO DISABLE AN TEXT BOX-----------------*/
function disableEnable(elm){
    getElement(elm).disabled = !getElement(elm).disabled
    if(getElement(elm).disabled == true)
      document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = "enabled"
    else
      document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = "disabled"
    
}


getElement("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    disableEnable("text-box2");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box1"/>
<input type="text"  id="text-box2"/>
<button id="button">disable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `setAttribute()` sets attribute values as strings.

The correct way:

- **disable**: `element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')`
- **enable**: `element.removeAttribute('disabled')`

If the 'disabled' attribute has any value at all, the element in question will be disabled. This means that passing either true or false (which will turn into "true" and "false" respectively) will both times disable your element.